# PHP include file error Warning: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, file, directory, filesystems, directory-structure

Cannot include file from the file located in the same parent directory.

This is the file structure

```
 - ROOT   
     -> source_code
        -> functions
            -> FileFunction.php
        -> template
            -> WebContent.php
```

I want to include FileFunction.php in the WebContent.php file but, it gives me a warning says cannot find a file in the directory.

Here is what I write on the WebContent.php file

```
include("../functions/FileFunction.php");
```

Comment: How you are calling `WebContent.php`

Comment: Try using: `include(__DIR__."/../functions/FileFunction.php");`

Comment: Paths are resolved relative to the point of execution,  which is not always where the include exists. If you want to construct an absolute path based on the directory that contains the file with the include use  __DIR__ as in `include(__DIR__."/../functions/FileFunction.php");`

Comment: Calling WebContent.php from another file called index.php. I just started to realize that could be a problem.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507